# Is there any image size limit for wordpress xml-rpc?

Tags: xml-rpc

I'm creating a plugin using the xml-rpc to send images. I'm able to send small images, those that are less than 1 MB. But I can't send bigger images. They won't be uploaded using the wp.uploadFile.

I thought maybe it was server restriction or server timeout, but no. Max upload is 50 MB, and I set timeout to 15 mins just to try.

Is there any restriction?

Comment: [Have you already read source code for XML-RPC](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/70fd806759b7a18d45950eb2c368e15949f1ef21/xmlrpc.php)? [link #2](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php)

Comment: Oh and turn off all other plugins and switch to the default theme.

Comment: hey , that is not the problem. My plugin works fine. I can upload files, the only problem is when a file is bigger than 2 mbs it  wont upload. Other than that everything is working.

Comment: What is no problem? Turn off everything except your custom plugin. And then setup another local test environment and try it there.

Comment: I could try that, but i've did some research and looks like they have some limitations. So im not 100% sure

Comment: So how about giving it a try... ? We can't help you without taking a hands-on look at your site. And as this site produces answers instead of _guesses_... :)

Comment: Didn't work. Still doing the same. uploads images less than 1mb, but no more than 2mbs.

Comment: What didn't work: Local vanilla environment or turning everything off? And did you look at the core files?

Comment: turning all off, yes i check the core files. Nothing so far. Still upload images under 1mb.